# Programmatically get the image sha of an image I just pushed

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, github-actions, sha256

I have a github action that builds a docker image and pushes it to our repo.

```
docker build -t mySuperCoolTag --build-arg PIP_INDEX_URL=${{ secrets.PIP_INDEX_URL }} .
docker push mySuperCoolTag
```

Per our deployment process, we take the SHA of the latest image, add it to our yaml files for K8s to read and use.

Originally, I incorrectly thought that the local SHA of the image was the same being pushed to the repo, and I grabbed it and added it to the file like so:

```
      docker images --no-trunc --quiet mySuperCoolTag
      dockerSHA=$(docker images --no-trunc --quiet mySuperCoolTag)
      
      #replace the current SHA in the configuration with the latest SHA
      sed -i -E "s/sha256:\w*/$dockerSHA/g" config-file.yaml
```

This ended up not being the SHA I was looking for.

`docker push` *does* output the expected SHA, but I'm not too sure how to programmatically grab that SHA save having a script read the output and grabbing it from there, but I'm hoping there is a more succinct way to do it. Any idea?

Comment: `docker push does output the expected SHA`, please share that output in your question.  Extracting the SHA from that output is probably not terribly hard to do, but you do not show what output you want to process.

Comment: I basically want the SHA that docker push outputs on a successful run to be isolated without any extra output so I can store it in a bash variable and use later in my script.

Comment: ok, but I do not have a docket setup to test, so what complete output do you get?  With that I can extract the value you want to isolate from it.

Comment: @Nic3500 
Ended up using this command instead:

    dockerSHA=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' mySuperCoolTag  | perl -wnE'say /sha256.*/g')

And it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using this command instead:

```
dockerSHA=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' mySuperCoolTag  | perl -wnE'say /sha256.*/g')
```

And it just works.